# split string on first occurence of a pattern only

Tags: r, regex, string, split

(Considering the large number of questions how to split a string in R, this might indicate some conceptual problem. At least I haven't found a simple solution to this question)

I have a string like `"42 despairing R programmers"` which I want to split on the first occurrence of a space, i.e.: the result should be `c(42, "despairing R programmers")`.

To me the simplest solution would be `strsplit()` having a parameter like `limit=n`, where the split is done at most `n` times (with some value meaning infinity). I feel there must be a really clean and simple solution, but I couldn't find one.

(In Perl the solution would be as simple as `split(' ', "42 despairing R programmers", 2)`)

Comment: In the package stringr the function str_split contains such a parameter called n.

Comment: From the solutions offered ` c(sub("^(\\w+)\\s?(.*)$", "\\1", s), sub("^(\\w+)\\s?(.*)$", "\\2", s))` has the problem that a string with a leading space is not handled correctly. The other border-cases seem OK.

I'd prefer `str_split_fixed()` if it were in the standard package; otherwise I'd still vote for extending the `strsplit()` with a formal parameter that limits the number of splits (or resulting list elements).